# Scrub XML innertext without specific Xpaths using c#

Tags: c#, xml

Requirements

- Need to iterate through each element in an XML file, and replace certain inner text such as < or >
- Need to reuse code against other external XML files, so cannot use specific Xpaths
- We are trying not to replace by reading full XML file contents into a string datatype

Input file

```
    <Statement>
      <Institution>
          <Account>
            <ID>100000001</ID>
            <Description>When Balance &lt; 1 million</Description>
            <Balance>
                <CloseBalance>1509.16</CloseBalance>
            </Balance>
            <Transaction>
                <Comment>Pmt &lt; SomeText &gt;</Comment>
            </Transaction>
          </Account>
      </Institution>
    </Statement>
```

Output File should be

```
    <Statement>
      <Institution>
          <Account>
            <ID>100000001</ID>
            <Description>When Balance LT 1 million</Description>
            <Balance>
                <CloseBalance>1509.16</CloseBalance>
            </Balance>
            <Transaction>
                <Comment>Pmt LT SomeText GT</Comment>
            </Transaction>
          </Account>
      </Institution>
    </Statement>
```

My problem is that the output shows only one child element with all the text concatenated?

```
<Statement><Institution>100000001When Balance LT 1 million1509.16Pmt LT SomeText GT</Institution>/Statement>
```

This is the code I've tried among other things like using nodelist, Xelements

```
private static void ScrubText()
{
  XDocument sourceDoc = XDocument.Parse(
    @"<Statement>
      <Institution>
          <Account>
            <ID>100000001</ID>
            <Description>When Balance &lt; 1 million</Description>
            <Balance>
                <CloseBalance>1509.16</CloseBalance>
            </Balance>
            <Transaction>
                <Comment>Pmt &lt; SomeText &gt;</Comment>
            </Transaction>
          </Account>
      </Institution>
    </Statement>");

  var elementList = sourceDoc.Root.Descendants().ToList();
  foreach (var element in elementList)
    element.SetValue(element.Value.Replace("<", "LT").Replace(">", "GT"));

  sourceDoc.Save(@"C:\temp\ResultDoc.xml");
}
```

Comment: for this it is probably best to open file as a txt file and replace &lt with LT and &gt with GT.  Using an xml library will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with LINQ to XML, you just need to target text nodes, not elements:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/fveGIU

```csharp
    private static void ScrubText()
    {
        XDocument sourceDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Statement>
          <Institution>
              <Account>
                <ID>100000001</ID>
                <Description>When Balance &lt; 1 million</Description>
                <Balance>
                    <CloseBalance>1509.16</CloseBalance>
                </Balance>
                <Transaction>
                    <Comment>Pmt &lt; SomeText &gt;</Comment>
                </Transaction>
              </Account>
          </Institution>
        </Statement>");
        var elementList = sourceDoc.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>();
        foreach (var element in elementList)
        {
            element.Value = element.Value.Replace("<", "LT").Replace(">", "GT");
        }

        sourceDoc.Save(@"C:\temp\ResultDoc.xml");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the working solution I was hoping for, we may need to have more control over the text scrubbing at a later time so the current requirement is to loop through each text element.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get a node with all of the text concatenated is because that is what XElement Value does.  From the documentation for XElement.Value:

*A String that contains all of the text content of this element. If there are multiple text nodes, they will be concatenated.*

I agree with @jdweng that opening the file as text would be easier to do a mass replace.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I also agree with @jdweng that the load file into text works but we are trying to avoid that solution at the moment.